# PHP How to make generate unique id like Instagram Post

Tags: php

Is it possible make generate id like instagram post but the id is unique ? How to make it ?

```
instagram.com/p/B39PuZrFKzd
```

What function to use ? To make short id with uppercase and lowercase word.

Comment: What is you question? Is it possible to generate a random number? the answer is obviously yes...

Comment: How to make it? Sorry for my bad questions

Comment: I'm kinda confused by this question too but I think he means a random id with both numbers and uppercase and lowercase letters. @Cukic0d